# Is it possible to use =FORMULATEXT(), or another command, to show the values in the cell rather than the referenced cellnumber

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering if it is possible to use =FORMULATEXT(), or another command to show the values in the cells rather than the cell number of the reference?

Let me give an example.

[image: Example]

Instead, I want it to say =10+10.

Comment: Do you need the result to appear in the worksheet? If not, you can do this using **Formulas > Evaluate Formula** from the ribbon.

Comment: I actually do. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea. But there is no such function in Excel right now. It is not possible to refer to the value in the cell instead of the position of the cell when using the function. You can submit feedback in this forum: [feedback](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/). Maybe Microsoft will update this feature in the future.